# ASP.NET MVC Project: Why is my form not accessing my controller method?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

When I try and submit the form in my 'Create.cshtml' file, I am brough to a "HTTP ERROR 405" page. The submission is not at all accessing the function in the controller.

Here is the controller post function:

```
        // POST: Books/Create
        [HttpPost]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public async Task<IActionResult> Create(CreateViewModel model)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Hello from create post function");
            // null check
            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(model.title) || string.IsNullOrEmpty(model.author) || model.yearPublished == null)
                return NotFound();

            // Create Book
            var book = new Book {
                Id = Guid.NewGuid(),
                Title = model.title,
                Author = model.author,
                YearPublished = model.yearPublished
            };

            // Check if book ID is original
            while (true) {
                
                // see if book exists
                var temp_book = await _context.Books.FirstOrDefaultAsync(b => b.Id == book.Id);

                // if it does break, else reassign the GUID
                if (temp_book == null)
                    break;
                else
                    book.Id = Guid.NewGuid();
            }

            // Save book to Books Table + Save
            _context.Books.Add(book);
            await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
            return RedirectToAction(nameof(Index));
        }
```

And here is the 'Create.cshtml' file with the form that is not connecting:

```
@model Deliverable4.Controllers.CreateViewModel

@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "Create";
}

<h1>@ViewData["Title"]</h1>

<div>
    <p>CREATE PAGE</p>
</div>

<form asp-action="Create" method="post">
    <label for="title">Title</label>
    <input name="title" id="title">

    <label for="author">Author</label>
    <input name="author" id="author">

    <label for="yearPublished">Year</label>
    <input name="yearPublished" id="yearPublished">

    <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

Can anyone tell me the issue?

Comment: Do you have automatic generation of antiforgery tokens configured?

Comment: From the code you provided, It's hard to find the reason, Have you tried to delete `[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]` attribute and try again?

Answer (score 1):

The problem seems to be that you tell your controller to validate the AntiForgeryToken but you do not provide the AntiForgeryToken in your Form. Add the AntiForgeryToken in your Form and the error should be resolved.

```
<form method="post" action="Create" >
@Html.AntiForgeryToken()
<!--rest of your Form elements-->
</form>
```